# Filter end date and add the filtered year to another excel column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset (**attached**) with the **start date** and **end date** as some of the columns.

I want to filter the **end date** in such as way that **end date > 09/01/2023** will move to fiscal year **2024**. And **end date < 09/01/2023** will stay as 2023.

If there are blank spaces, it should just ignore them.

I have another column called **Year** and I want the values (the year 2023 or 2024) to be displayed on this.

Thanks for your help!

[image]

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: This is a simple [`IF`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2). Did you try that?

Comment: I want the output to look like this :https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR406.png

Comment: @EmilioSilva I tried =IF(D2:D55>9/1/2023,"2024","2023") but this fills up even the blank rows (which i want it to be empty if there is not end date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,B2:B36,
     IF((a="")+(a="FT Seasonal"),"",(IF(a="NA",DATE(2023,8,31),a)>=DATE(2023,9,1))+2023))
```

---

Or, without Spill:

```
=IF(OR(B2={"","FT Seasonal"}),"",(IF(B2="NA",DATE(2023,8,31),B2)>=DATE(2023,9,1))+2023)
```

---